# Solve following trigonometric equation

Tags: trigonometry

How to solve $$2\sin(x) /  (1+2\cos(x)) = \sqrt{3}/2$$ where $0< x <180$.

(Final answer may be in inverse form)

Comment: I can guess it as $\frac{\pi}{3}$

Comment: @AWertheim I ended at squaring both sides and stuck there :
3/4 = ( 4sin(x)*sin(x) )/(1 + 4cos(x)*cos(x) + 4cos(x)).
But thanx to Harish I got the approach.

Comment: @KunalKrishna good! glad to hear it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let $\sin{x} = a $

and as $ \cos^2{x} = 1 -\sin^2{x}  $

$$ 2*a / (1 + 2 \sqrt {1-a^2}) = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} $$

solving we get

$$ a = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{7} \pm 5*\frac{\sqrt{3}}{14}  $$

$$x = \sin^{-1}(a) $$

for  $$ a = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{7} + 5*\frac{\sqrt{3}}{14}  $$ you get x = $\sin^{-1}(\sqrt3/2) = \pi /3 $

And for $$ a = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{7} - 5*\frac{\sqrt{3}}{14}  $$ It can be eliminated as $sine$ cannot be negative in first and second quadrant because in question it is given $ 0< x <180 $

So solution will be only $ x = \frac{\pi}{3}$

Comment: exactly what I wanted, thanx. I was trying to break (1+2cos(x)) ,in vain.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to go about this problem, one way taking $c=\cos$ and $s=\sin$, 
$\frac{2s}{1+2c}=\frac {\sqrt{3}} 2$ so $2s=\frac{\sqrt{3}}2+c\times\sqrt{3}$ which is $2s-\sqrt{3}\times c=\frac{\sqrt3}2$, the trick with the LHS is to consider the harmonic form, if you haven't come across this before search it, this should lead you to the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Using  [Weierstrass substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution),  $$\sin x=\frac{2t}{1+t^2},\cos x=\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2} \text{ where }t=\tan \frac x2  $$

$$\frac{2\sin x}{1+2\cos x} = \frac{\sqrt{3}}2,$$

$$\implies \frac{4t}{1+t^2+2(1-t^2)}= \frac{\sqrt{3}}2 \implies \sqrt3t^2+8t-3\sqrt3=0$$

$$\implies t=\frac{-8\pm\sqrt{8^2-4\sqrt3(-3\sqrt3)}}{2\sqrt3}$$

As $0<x<180^\circ,0<x<90^\circ\implies \tan \frac x2>0 $

Either  $t=-3\sqrt3\implies \tan \frac x2=-3\sqrt3<0$

or $t=\frac1{\sqrt3}\implies \tan \frac x2=\frac1{\sqrt3}=\tan30^\circ$

$\implies  \frac x2=180^\circ n+30^\circ$ where $n$ is any integer

$\implies x=360^\circ n+60^\circ$

As $0<x<180^\circ, 0<360^\circ n+60^\circ<180^\circ\implies -1<n<1\implies n=0\implies x=...$

Comment: @KunalKrishna, how about this method?

Comment: nice solution.very methodical. thanX

Comment: @KunalKrishna, my pleasure. Nice to hear that.